# how to set breakpoint on function in a shared library which has not been loaded in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, breakpoints

I have a shared library `libtest.so` which will be loaded into the the main program using `dlopen`. Function `test()` reside in `libtest.so` and will be called in the main program through `dlsym`. Is there any way I could set up a break point on `test`?

Please note that the main programm has not been linked to `libtest.so` during linking time. Otherwise , I should be able to set the break point although it is a pending action.  In my case, when I do `b test`, gdb will tell me `Function "test" not defined`.

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint on `test` after loading `libtest.so` with `dlopen`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually gdb should tell you that it's able to resolve the symbol in the future, when new libraries are loaded:

```
(gdb) b test
Function "test" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (test) pending.
(gdb) r
```

And later on once the .so object is loaded, it will resolve the breakpoint, e.g.:

```
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Breakpoint 1 at 0xcafebebe
Pending breakpoint 1 - "test" resolved
```

Comment: On the GDB I'm using, even if I "set breakpoint pending on" it will NOT ask me if I want the pending behavior if the symbol is undefined. It just tells me "Can't find member bla bla Hint try tab bla bla"

Answer (score 2):

First set

```
catch load libtest.so
```

And when gdb will stop on this catch do

```
b test
```

Answer (score 2):

> > how to set a breakpoint on a shared lib.
>
> It's quite common to have a breakpoint inside a shared library. Shared libraries can be loaded and unloaded explicitly, and possibly repeatedly, as the program is executed. To support this use case, gdb updates breakpoint locations whenever any shared library is loaded or unloaded. Typically, you would set a breakpoint in a shared library at the beginning of your debugging session, when the library is not loaded, and when the symbols from the library are not available. When you try to set breakpoint, gdb will ask you if you want to set a so called pending breakpoint—breakpoint whose address is not yet resolved.

quote from https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html

> > (gdb) b object5.c:66
> >     No source file named object5.c.

maybe you can use "set directory the_location_of_object5.c_file" to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to specify the filename and der function, e.g.:

```
b object5.c:test
```

This should be unique. Maybe you want also to specify the path to the source code (as already suggested) by:

```
set directories path_of_object5.c
```